# Can't retrieve image from API - SSL certificate error

Tags: python, api, ssl, urllib

I'm trying to fetch an image from Nasa's APOD API and save it to my computer, but when the request gets sent, I get an SSL certificate error. I'm not sure how to fix it since I've never dealt with this before.

This is what i get:

```
raise SSLError(e)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1124)
```

Here's my code:

```
import nasapy
import os
from datetime import datetime
import urllib.request
from IPython.display import Image,display,Audio
import ssl

def nasa_apod(ctx):
    key = "#####################"
    nasa = nasapy.Nasa(key=key)

    dtm = datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    apod = nasa.picture_of_the_day(date=dtm, hd=True)

    print(apod)
    if apod["media_type"] == "image":
        title = dtm + "_" + apod["title"].replace(" ", "_").replace(":", "_") + ".jpg"
        image_dir = "Astro_images"

        dir_res = os.path.exists(image_dir)

        if dir_res == False:
            os.makedirs(image_dir)
        else:
            print("Directory already exists! ")

    filename =os.path.join(image_dir, title)
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url=apod["hdurl"], context=ctx) as u, \
        open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(u.read())

    if ("date" in apod.keys()):
        print("Date image released: ", apod["date"])
        print("\n")
    if ("copyright" in apod.keys()):
        print("This image is owned by: ", apod["copyright"])
        print("\n")
    if ("title" in apod.keys()):
        print("Title of the image: ", apod["title"])
        print("\n")
    if ("explanation" in apod.keys()):
        print("Description for the image: ", apod["explanation"])
        print("\n")
    if ("hdurl" in apod.keys()):
        print("URL for this image: ", apod["hdurl"])
        print("\n")

    display(Image(os.path.join(image_dir, title)))


ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

nasa_apod(ctx)
```

I've hidden the key for security reasons.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: " I get an SSL certificate error. " Maybe provide that error in your question? As well as exact URL you try to hit. Did you try the same URL with other clients and what results did you get?

Comment: Here it is: 'urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1124)>'

Comment: Put details in your question, not as comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to replace `urllib.request.urlretrieve` by `urllib.request.urlopen` and determine a custom **ssl** context before you call `nasa_apod` method, then your program should look like this:

```
def nasa_apod(ctx):
    key = "#####"
    nasa = nasapy.Nasa(key=key)

    dtm = datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    apod = nasa.picture_of_the_day(date=dtm, hd=True)

    print(apod)
    if apod["media_type"] == "image":
        title = dtm + "_" + apod["title"].replace(" ", "_").replace(":", "_") + ".jpg"
        image_dir = "Astro_images"

        dir_res = os.path.exists(image_dir)

        if dir_res == False:
            os.makedirs(image_dir)
        else:
            print("Directory already exists! ")

    filename=os.path.join(image_dir, title) 
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url=apod["hdurl"], context=ctx) as u, \
        open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(u.read())

    if ("date" in apod.keys()):
        print("Date image released: ", apod["date"])
        print("\n")
    if ("copyright" in apod.keys()):
        print("This image is owned by: ", apod["copyright"])
        print("\n")
    if ("title" in apod.keys()):
        print("Title of the image: ", apod["title"])
        print("\n")
    if ("explanation" in apod.keys()):
        print("Description for the image: ", apod["explanation"])
        print("\n")
    if ("hdurl" in apod.keys()):
        print("URL for this image: ", apod["hdurl"])
        print("\n")

    display(Image(os.path.join(image_dir, title)))


ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

nasa_apod(ctx)
```

Comment: Alright, but what's 'file_name' next to open?

Comment: It also tells me requests.urlopen can't have the parameter 'filename'

Comment: NEVER do that! `ctx.check_hostname = False` and `ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE`  are removing all protections coming from HTTPS so you might as well be doing plain HTTP, as HTTPS becomes useless then.

Comment: okay I totally agree with [@patrick-mevzek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6368697/patrick-mevzek) I write this answer as a possible solution to the problem raised above, on the other hand I think it returned an error and I edited the answer so that `filename=os.path.join(image_dir, title`) is no longer passed as a parameter in `urllib.request.urlopen(url=apod["hdurl"], context=ctx)`.

Comment: The code works now, but I still get SSL certificate errors though, so the issue is not solved. Here's the exception: `requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1124)`

Comment: Because the causes of this problem are varied you can try and investigate different ways, you could "skip" http/https/ssl issues using `ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context`, although some media recommend avoiding the above option by installing the following module using pip `pip install certifi` or `python -m pip install --upgrade certifi`